# Migrate from Tomcat to Weblogic - Directory Mapping

Tags: tomcat, directory, weblogic12c

I have local directory path in tomcat 6 server.xml using below line

```
<Context docBase="C:/uploads/" path="/File" reloadable="false"/>
```

and reading this to my application based on below line which i defined in config file

```
ExportUrl_Internal=http://localhost:8180/File/
```

When i migrate the application from tomcat 6 to weblogic 12c,

I tried this piece of code in weblogic.xml

```
<virtual-directory-mapping>
        <local-path>C:/uploads/</local-path>
        <url-pattern>/File</url-pattern>
</virtual-directory-mapping>
```

But i couldn't get the path. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Looks more or less correct. Have you tried `<url-pattern>/File/*</url-pattern>`